# AttributeError in 'contains' attribute after lower() operation on str in pandas Series

Tags: pandas, string, contains, lowercase

```
pd.col.str.contains('something')
```

The above one works fine, giving Boolean values. However,

```
pd.col.str.lower().contains("something")
```

gives back an error stating:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: pd.col.str.lower().str.contains("something")

Comment: Or pass `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to `contains` as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).

Comment: Yes I understood now. Thanks for the prompt reply.